# Handler for Button Declared in axml Layout

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm guessing this is easy, but can't seem to nail it.

I want to define a button in an axml file, and link the click up to a handler. I know that I can manually set the handler using `FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button2).Click += buttonClick;`, however I'm wondering if that's necessary.

How do I have the handler bound by merit of `android:onClick="buttonClick"` in the axml file? The error thrown is

`Could not find a method buttonClick(View) in the activity class md....Activity1 for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'Button1'`

```
[Activity (Label = "SlidingMenuExample", MainLauncher = true)]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.menu);  
    }

    public void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }

    // This seems similar to the Java approaches. Why doesn't it work?
    //public void buttonClick(View view) {
    //} 

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 2"
        android:onClick="buttonClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that. You need to add a reference to `Mono.Android.Export`.

Then you need to annotate your method like:

```
[Export("buttonClick")]
private void ButtonClick(View view)
{

}
```

If you don't annotate the method, the Java world won't know of your method in the Activity.

Comment: Ahh Cool. Thanks very much for that, it's good to know! I was thinking that it was a bit of a stupid question, but now I'm glad that I asked :-)